# How can I access a specific depth of an associative array with variable variables

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, variable-variables

I've been hitting my head on this problem for some time now. I am working on a piece of software that creates a tree from a MySQL result checking for changes between each row to decide where in the tree to put the new data.

I'm now at a dead end while trying to understand how I can dynamically tell PHP to address different parts of my array.

I though about using variable variables but it doesn't seem to be working. To make my life easier I tried to set up a test file in which to test this behavior and this is the result...

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "test"
    ],
    1 => [
        "name" => "test",
        "data" => [
            "content" => 5
        ]
    ]
];

$ref = 'array["1"]["name"]';

echo $ref."\n";
echo $$ref;
```

**Output**

```
array["1"]["name"] 
Notice: Undefined variable: array["1"]["name"] in P:\xampp\htdocs\assets\php\test.php on line 23
```

I was instead expecting something like `test`.

I would also like to mention that I've tried the `${}` method but I doesn't affect the array, but instead adds the data to another variable those rare times it doesn't output an error.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after thinking about the problem once again I came up with a work-around to achieve the intended result.
I decided to use references make with `&$var`.

I, so, decided to tweak the code to create an array of each step to do to arrive at the intended location, instead of a string. Example follows:

```
// Old method
$ref = 'array["1"]["name"];

// New method
$ref = ["1", "name"];
```

The code then follows by cycling through the array referencing the original array but slowly deeper...

```
// Referencing the original array
$referencedArray = &$array;

// Going one step at the time inside the nested array
foreach ($ref as $k => $v) {
   $referencedArray = &$referencedArray[$rav];
}
```

I believe this solution could fit my case, but if you have any suggestions please let me know.